# Structural directives without `*`?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a simple directive `myNgIf` which is a basic simplification of `ngIf` :

```
import { Directive, Input, TemplateRef, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
@Directive({
  selector: '[myNgIf]'
})
export class MyNgIfDirective {

  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef) { }

  @Input() set myNgIf(condition: boolean) {
    if (condition) {
      this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    } else {
      this.viewContainer.clear();
    }
  }

}
```

The markup is :

```
111
 <div *myNgIf="true">
   hello
 </div>
222
```

This ^ obviously shows :

[image]

I already know what's going on here — The template is desugared to:

```
<ng-template>
 <div...>
</ng-template>
```

And that template is injected to the ctor , where we later using it in :

```
 this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
                                                   ^
 --------------------------------------------------|
```

But then I thought , what if I want it to work the same , BUT without using an `*` :

```
<div myNgIf="true">
   hello
 </div>
```

I already inject  `ViewContainerRef` so I have an anchor of *"where to inject"*

But now I don't have "what to inject"

**Question:**

For learning purpose , How can I reference the current element of which myNgIf is applied to ?

NB
I already know that I will see the content at start because div is a browser known parsed element while ng-template is not- But again - I'm asking for learning purpose.

[**STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r1urkt?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: `How can I reference the current element of which myNgIf is applied to ?` Have you tried to inject `ElementRef`? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e7jhvy?file=app/my-ng-if.directive.ts

Comment: @yurzui yeah I thought about it but I wanted to show/hide the content conditionally via `this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView`. The problem is that  `createEmbeddedView` takes a tempalte which I don't have ( since It is now not-desugared to template).

Comment: We can't create TemplateRef manually. It uses internal data that is created during compilation

Comment: @yurzui Ok so is there a non-*-way to do :https://i.imgur.com/AdDc6RW.jpg ?

Comment: There is always way to do something wrong:)

Comment: @yurzui :-) You're right. I'm just curious.  becuase when you think of it , it's just injecteting an element's content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here would be my solution:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fhhpek?file=app%2Fmy-ng-if.directive.ts

The `Renderer2` is used to directly access the DOM.
I mark the content DOM node with a comment and detach it as soon as the directive is loaded. Then it is reattached later, if the condition evaluates to true.

Disclaimer: This is really ugly and not production ready ;-)

Comment: BTW why did you use `pipe(map(` rather than `map` ? ( asking to learn)

Comment: That's the pipeable syntax you really should always use now: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md